# Python TypeError: draw() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I am trying to make an image appear on the pygame screen but I keep getting the error:   TypeError: draw() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) when I run the 2nd file.

Here are the codes:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


# Create a class called Person
class Person:
    def __init__(self, newX, newY):        ###defines paramaters###
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY


    def draw(window):                      ###loads and draws the image###
        img = pygame.image.load("dude.gif")
        window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))   


    def moveLeft(self):
        # Change x so that the object can move left
        pass



    def moveRight(self):
        # Change x so that the object can move right
        pass



    def moveUp(self):
        # Change y so that the object can move up
        pass



    def moveDown(self):
        # Change y so that the object can move down
        pass
```

Here is the second file:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from Person import *

# Creates the screen to draw on
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Allows a key that is held down to count as multiple presses
pygame.key.set_repeat(100,100)

# Creates a Person object named guy
guy = Person(50,50)

# Event Loop
while True:
    # Colors the screen white
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # Draw your person on the screen
    guy.draw(screen)                            

    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.update()


    # Check for key presses and mouse clicks
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Determine if the user has closed the window or pressed escape
        if event.type==QUIT or (event.type==KEYUP and event.key==K_ESCAPE):
            # Quit the program
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # Check if an arrow key is pressed and 
        # move guy in the correct direction
        elif event.type==KEYDOWN:

            if event.key==K_UP: 
                guy.moveUp()

            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                guy.moveDown()

            elif event.key==K_LEFT:
                guy.moveLeft()

            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                guy.moveRight()
```

Comment: You're missing the `self` argument in your method signatures. `def draw(self, window):`, not `def draw(window):`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, thanks -- there are a lot of very similar questions, but I was having trouble finding one that was completely spot-on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just searched with Google for `"takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" missing self`.  This question was **the first hit**, the one that I used as a dupe target was the second.  (Wow Google updates SO content quickly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `draw` method should be defined as `def draw(self, window):`:

```
def draw(self, window):
    img = pygame.image.load("dude.gif")

    # and after all, you're using self here
    window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Thank you. I hate that self thing

Comment: That self thing isn't something to hate. It is me and it is you. It is the very essence of object oriented programming, the reference between an object an it's abilities. What is coming out of my mouth???

Comment: *nod*. "Explicit is better than implicit" -- very much the zen of Python.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, then please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark, @bowser